# File module vs folder module in the NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Lets say, I have one entry.js file `entry.js`

```
var t = require('./test'); //it can be file or folder module
```

If I have a folder and a file named "test"in the same package as that of entry.js, how the execution will happen as both have the same name? which module has the highest priority?

Answer (score 2):

The checking priority will be next:

1. ./test.js
2. ./test.json
3. ./test.node
4. ./test/index.js
5. ./test/index.node

Sources:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

Answer (score 0):

Frome `reqire`'s docs:

> Once Node.js finds the node_modules folder, it will then attempt to load the
>   given module either as a (.js) Javascript file or as a named sub-directory.
>   And, if it finds the named sub-directory, it will then attempt to load the file
>   in various ways. So, for example, if you make a request to load the module, "test":
>
> ```
> var utils = require( "test" );
> ```
>
> ... Node.js will perform a hierarchical directory search for "node_modules"
>   and "test" in the following ways:
>
> ```
> ./node_modules/test.js
> ./node_modules/test/index.js
> ./node_modules/test/package.json
> ```

So, answer is: `File` first, `Directory` second, `Module` third.